# Testing Ubuntu Touch on Intel tablet

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I'd like to test Ubuntu Touch on a Dell Venue 11 7130 tablet with Intel hardware and found seemingly appropriate images of pre-installed systems on cdimages.ubuntu.com. But unfortunately, after any img file from one of the ubuntu-touch folders with dd I only get an unusable USB stick with an undefined file system. Please help me getting a bootable stick.

Regards

Uwe